# Multi select in datatables cannot filter duplications

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've created a filter with bootstrap multi select [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bk18fOqYH2bdS4Ta3upR?p=preview), the filter works fine with unique words - but not with duplicate ones,

So - if my filter searches for "Ashton Cox" and add more keys to search by using the multi select - than it's works well,

For example :

Search for : "Ashton Cox" , "Tiger Nixon" , "Garrett Winters" = OK

Search for : "Senior angular Developer" = gives me all results starts with the word "Senior".

Here is the filter :

```
table.column(0).every( function () {
     var that = this;
     $('#filter').on( 'change', function () {
         select_val = $('#filter').val();
         var new_arr = [];
         $.each(select_val,function(k,v){
             new_arr.push(v.replace(/\s+/g, "|"));
         });
         console.log(new_arr);
         var new_str = new_arr.join('|');
         if ( that.search() !== new_str ) {
             that.search((new_str), true )
                 .draw();
         }
     });
});
```

I guess i could remove the duplicate keys, but i'm looking for a better way...

Comment: So, whats your actual problem?

Comment: When the first word in a sentence appears more then once - it does not filter by the rest of the sentence....